# Can I set a default show levels in a Table of Contents?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I set in MS Word document "show leveles" to 5 by default in Custom Table of Contents ? 
When I create a new document and I choose "References" -> "Custom Table of Contents", "show levels" is always set to 3.

Thank You

Comment: Not that I know of. Are you writing that many documents that have such a deep hierarchy of headings?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, really. What you can do, though, is create a custom table of contents that has 5 levels, select it, and then click **Table of Contents** > **Save Selection to the Table of Contents Gallery**. That way, the 5-level TOC will at least be available as an option in new documents that you create, so you won't have to re-create it each time.